# Find the Project, Bucket, Compute Instance Details for GCP Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How we can find the details programmatically about GCP Infrastructure like various Folders, Projects, Compute Instances, datasets etc. which can help to have a better understanding of GCP platform.

Regards,

Neeraj

Comment: Use the Google Cloud SDKs. Pick your language and search on Google for examples. StackOverflow also has lots of examples. Note, Google has over 250 services, you so you need to be specific on which service and language when searching. Google Cloud SDK Homepage: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/

Answer (score 3):

There is a service in GCP called [Cloud Asset Inventory](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/overview). Cloud Asset Inventory is a storage service that keeps a five week history of Google Cloud Platform (GCP) asset metadata.

It allows you to [export](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/exporting-to-cloud-storage) all asset metadata at a certain timestamp to Google Cloud Storage or BigQuery.

It also allows you to [search resources and IAM policies](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-resources).

It supports a wide range of resource types, including:

**Resource Manager**

- google.cloud.resourcemanager.Organization
- google.cloud.resourcemanager.Folder
- google.cloud.resourcemanager.Project

**Compute Engine**

- google.compute.Autoscaler
- google.compute.BackendBucket
- google.compute.BackendService
- google.compute.Disk
- google.compute.Firewall
- google.compute.HealthCheck
- google.compute.Image
- google.compute.Instance
- google.compute.InstanceGroup

...

**Cloud Storage**

- google.cloud.storage.Bucket

**BigQuery**

- google.cloud.bigquery.Dataset
- google.cloud.bigquery.Table

Find the full list [here](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/supported-asset-types).

The equivalent service in AWS is called [AWS Config](https://aws.amazon.com/config).

Answer (score 0):

I have found open source tool named as "forseti Security", which is easy to install and use. It has 5 major components in it.

```
Inventory : Regularly collects the data from GCP and store the results in cloudSQL under the table “gcp_inventory”. In order to refer to the latest inventory information you can refer to the max value of column : inventory_index_id.

Scanner : It periodically compares the policies applied on GCP resources with the data collected from Inventory. It stores the scanner information in table “scanner_index”

Explain : it helps to manage the cloud IAM policies.

Enforcer : This component use Google Cloud API to enforce the policies you have set in GCP platform.

Notifier : It helps to send notifications to Slack, Cloud Storage or SendGrid as show in Architecture diagram above.
```

You can find the official documentation [here](https://forsetisecurity.org/docs/latest/).

I tried using this tool and found it really useful.